# Quantifying Ill-posedness using Sobolev Space Estimates

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I've been learning about ill-posed/inverse problems, and I'm having a hard time parsing/understanding the following, which seems crucial to the theory:

Say we have an operator $A:L^2(\Omega)\rightarrow Y$ such that for some $\alpha,m,M>0$ and independent of $f$ we have the estimate

$$
m\|f\|_{H_0^{-\alpha}(\Omega)}\leq \|Af\|_{Y}\leq M\|f\|_{H_0^{-\alpha}(\Omega)}
$$
Here $H_0^{-\alpha}(\Omega)$ are dual Sobolev spaces.  Then, I frequently see claims of the following type:

1. "$A^{-1}$ exists but is unbounded as an operator from $Y$ to $L^2(\Omega)$."
2. "$\alpha$ measures the degree of ill-posedness of solving the problem $Af=g$"
3. "$Af$ is $\alpha$-smoother than $f$"

I roughly understand the second and third statements and how they relate to each other in terms of Fourier transforms (though I welcome second opinions).  Is there a simple functional analysis argument for the first statement, showing that such an estimate guarantees that $A^{-1}$ exists but is unbounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $A^{-1}: Y\to L^2(\Omega)$ is bounded, i.e. $$\|A^{-1} f\|_2\leq c\|f\|_Y,\ \forall\ f\in Y\tag{1}$$

where $c>0$ is a constant. We get from $(1)$ and from your inequality that $$\|A^{-1} f\|_2\leq cM\|A^{-1}f\|_{H^{-\alpha}},\ \forall f\in Y$$

or equivalently $$\|g\|_2\leq cM\|g\|_{H^{-\alpha}},\ \forall \ g\in L^2(\Omega)$$

Do you know what is the problem with the last inequality?

Comment: I'm guessing the inequality should go the other way, but I don't quite see why yet.  I'll have to think about it a little more.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If you can't figure out the solution, please send a message here to me.